# Unable to turn off notice errors in PHP 5.3.2

Tags: php, error-handling

I recently migrated to PHP 5.3.2, and realized that I am unable to turn off notice errors in my site now. I went to php.ini, and in these lines:

```
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
;   E_ALL | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

...I've tried setting everything (and I restart apache each time), but I am unable to get rid of notices.

The only way I'm able to get rid of notice errors is by setting :

```
display_errors = Off
```

That is, of course, not something I can do since I need to see errors to fix them, and I would like to see errors on the webpage that I am coding rather than log them somewhere.

Can someone help? Is this a bug in PHP 5.3.2 or something I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your time!

P. S. Also, would anyone know how I can get PHP 5.3.2 to support the .php3 extension?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured what was going wrong. I set error_reporting in my code, which was overwriting the php.ini error_reporting.

Now the reason that that same stuff was working until I upgraded to PHP 5.3.2 was this - in my code, I set the error_reporting command:

> error_reporting(6143);

I should've set it as:

> error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

I'm guessing the meaning of 6143 is different in PHP 5.3.2 compared to in 4.1 (or whatever my earlier version was).

As for the php3 extension, it was to be set in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf file:

> AddHandler php5-script .php .php3
>
> AddType text/html .php

Thank you, sourcez, for your suggestions!

Comment: `E_NOTICE` has a value of 4, which is (and always was) enabled in level 6143 (which happened to be the value of `E_ALL` in PHP 5.2.x: the only difference between that and `E_ALL` in PHP 5.3.x is that 6143 *excludes* the two newly introduced modes `E_DEPRECATED` and `E_USER_DEPRECATED`—but since they didn't exist in 5.2.x, that's pretty trivial).  So this change doesn't really explain the behaviour you've observed.

Comment: Thanks.. Helped..!!

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same error today in my website where i use TCPDF Library to generate PDFs. It was working fine but suddenly i started to get the following error today

```
Severity: 8192
Message: Imagick::clone method is deprecated .....
```

Might be the hosting provider updated PHP or Imagick. PHP - 5.4 and Imagick - 3.x

So to get rid of this in my code, i set error_reporting as

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

And this will show the errors but not the deprecated notices. Meanwhile I can change my code to support the new version of Imagick.